# CakePHP Form Helper - Show error class, but not error message

Tags: cakephp

I'm attempting to customize the error output on the CakePHP 2.0 form helper.  Currently, the form renders error messages below the input and applies an 'error' class to the input's label.

I have found that I can either disable error reporting altogether for an input, or output the error class and message.

I would like the *error class* to be applied to the label of the offending inputs WITHOUT any message below.

How do you **turn off the error message** outputting for a form, BUT **still apply error classes** to offending labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FormHelper::input()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput) has a `format` option. It is a

> format template for element order. Any element that is not in the array, will not be in the output.
>
> Default input format order: array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'after', 'error')

You can pass the default format, leaving out the `'error'`:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'some_field',
     array('format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'after'))
);
```

That should produce the input markup without the error message.

If you want to apply this to multiple inputs in your form, you should keep it DRY:

```
$format = array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'after');
echo $this->Form->input(
    'some_field',
     array('format' => $format)
);
echo $this->Form->input(
    'some_other_field',
     array('format' => $format)
);
```

It is also possible to set the default format for *all* inputs of a form by passing the format to [`FormHelper::create()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelpercreate) as `inputDefaults`:

```
$this->Form->create(
    'MyModel',
    array(
        'inputDefaults' => array(
            'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'after')
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This is great.  But is there a way to set this for an entire $this->Form element?  I'm dealing with a rather complex form, and am looking to avoid adding configuration details to each input...

Comment: There is no central option that I know of. Added an example that at least specifies the format only once. If you absolutely don't want to touch your `input()` calls you can override `FormHelper::input()` in a custom class, but that doesn't make it much cleaner, I think.

Comment: Working off of your suggestions, I found that you can set the 'format' option in the $this->Form->create() call, and that will apply it to every field in the form.  If you could add this to the answer, for posterity, I'd appreciate it.  Ex: `$this->Form->create('ModelName', array('inputDefaults' => array('format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'after'))));`

Comment: Didn't know about `inputDefaults`. Great you now found the best solution yourself, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some of this manually. First turn off the validations, and label generation on the Form Helper.

```
echo $this->Form->input('myfield', array('error' => false, 'label' => false));
```

Then to add the class to the create the label and add the error class if validations have failed. To find out which validations failed check the invalidFields array like so:

```
$error = null;
if (isset($this->invalidFields['Model']['myfield'])) {
    $error = 'error';
}

echo $this->Form->label('myfield', 'My Field', array('class' => $error));
```

Comment: Thanks.  This would work, but I'm looking for a way to do this without having to explicitly check/set each field's label class. pixelistik's answer was closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make use of `Form->error('field_name')` which should return nothing if there is no errors.

```
$error = $this->Form->error('field_name');
echo $this->Html->input('field_name', array(
    'class' => !empty($error) ? 'error' : null,
    'error' => false
));
```

You now have the $error with the usual markup for errors that could be displayed in another location.

There is no way to get around without checks, the `Form->input()` method is a convinience method that does all these things like errors, divs, labels automatically which can be done through `Form->label()`, `Form->checkbox()`, `Form->select()` etc which is the basic elements only.

One of the options that can be passed to `Form->create()` is `inputDefaults` which you can use to set defaults for all the other form elements. This will not help much as you are doing field by field. (`'error' => false` would help a bit)

The other thing you can do is make your own form helper, extending the core FormHelper and customise the input method to do this all automatically. You can use [aliasing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-and-configuring-helpers) to load your custom helper into `$this->Form` to be used as normal. See the bottom of this section.

You can also overload the input method in `AppHelper` but that is not a good place for it.